# Trick preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation to fire on viewController change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using `MSNavigationPaneViewController` [from here](https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSNavigationPaneViewController) and have rotation sort of working.
I've overridden the rotation methods in my root `UINavigationController`

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.topViewController != nil) {
        return [appDelegate.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.topViewController != nil) {
        return [appDelegate.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
}
```

which I push the `MSNavigationPaneViewController` with using `presentViewController: animated:completion:` and I have rotation working so certain views can have different orientations. The problem is, each view that has a different orientation needs the user to tilt the phone to change the orientation at which point it locks on the correct orientation.
I've done tons of reading to get this working and it seems I need `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` to fire before each view is loaded, but it's not firing.
I think it's not firing because the `MSNavigationPaneViewController` isn't changing view controllers using `presentViewController`.
This is the code used by `MSNavigationPaneViewController` to change the view

```
- (void)setPaneViewController:(UIViewController *)paneViewController
{
    if (_paneViewController == nil) {

        paneViewController.view.frame = _paneView.bounds;
        _paneViewController = paneViewController;
        [self addChildViewController:_paneViewController];
        [_paneView addSubview:_paneViewController.view];
        [_paneViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    } else if (_paneViewController != paneViewController) {

        paneViewController.view.frame = _paneView.bounds;
        [_paneViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [self addChildViewController:paneViewController];

        void(^transitionCompletion)(BOOL finished) = ^(BOOL finished) {
            [_paneViewController removeFromParentViewController];
            [paneViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            _paneViewController = paneViewController;
        };

        [self transitionFromViewController:_paneViewController
                          toViewController:paneViewController
                                  duration:0
                                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                animations:nil
                                completion:transitionCompletion];
    }
}
```

which looks like it's just switching the viewController and therefor not calling `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`

Is there any way to force `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` to be called, or to trick it into be called maybe by a hidden view?

Thanks

EDIT ----

I totally understand how the new rotation system works in iOS6 and that it's down to the root to manage it. However `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` only seems to be called if the next view is being `presented` with one of the correct methods. Not if the window is just switched.
So I do actually need a way to trick this to be called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can trick the window into re-valuating its supported interface orientations by resetting its rootViewController.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIWindow *window = [[app windows] objectAtIndex:0];
UIViewController *root = window.rootViewController;
window.rootViewController = nil;
window.rootViewController = root;
```

You'd need to make sure that when this code executes, -supportedInterfaceOrientations of the root view controller returns the proper mask (corresponding to how you want to force the orientation).

Be aware, this hack can cause a quick flash on the screen and glitch any ongoing animations.

Comment: Thanks. This did make the rotation change :-) The only problem with this solution is that any modal views currently displayed, end up hidden. Possibly behind the rootView. I have managed a hack work around though to re-present the current modal view after switching rootViewController. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in iOS 7, for me at least, in a parent/child viewController setup.

Comment: Works on iOS 7. Like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

`preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` will not be called on controllers within a `UINavigationController`.

You are going to have to subclass `UINavigationController` and then implement this feature yourself. You'd simply want to delegated to `topViewController`.

For reference check out: http://code.shabz.co/post/32051014482/ios-6-supportedorientations-with-uinavigationcontroller

I also found this implementation of a `UINavigationController` subclass: https://gist.github.com/3842178

Comment: Hi thanks. I have already done this to get the shouldRotate working. The problem is preferredInterfaceOrientation isn't called even in the nav controller unless you 'present' the next view and not just switch it out.

Comment: Hi all,
I'm new to iOS development, can some one guide me how to add this sub class.