# Migration from iOS 5 to iOS 7: rotation not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, ios7

For two days I am working on iOS app to fix the rotation issue, but no success. I have search everywhere in internet to find any solution, but couldn't find anything which fix my app rotation.

I have added all new function that introduced in iOS 6 for rotation to my AppDelegate class.

This is my code in AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    HomeViewController *controller;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
         controller = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"iPadHomePage" bundle:  nil];
    }
    else {
         controller = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"HomePage" bundle: nil];
    }
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [controllers addObject:controller];
    navController.viewControllers = controllers;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

When I google I found out that I shouldn't use `[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view]` as this will not work with iOS 6, so I replace it with `[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController]` in AppDelegate class, but then I am getting an error in main class.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key labelName

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you searched for this error? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSUnknownKeyException+setValue%3AforUndefinedKey%3A+this+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant+for+the+key

Comment: @rmaddy, yes I have, but I only get the error if I use [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view]</code> instead of [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController] and I have checked my code and xib file, I haven't rename or delete any properties or any instance variable.

Comment: But you shouldn't use the call to `addSubview` for your main view.

Comment: But addSubView was working so far, when I build the app long time ago with iOS 5 and I know now by release of iOS 6 I have to use [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController] and that is what I am trying to do, which was discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923788/ios-6-rotation-not-working, but somehow it's not working for me. I know I am missing something, but not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue.
Replacing the code `[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view]` with `[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController]` is not enough, also the order is important. I move `[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController]; [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` to the end before `return YES;` and now all works fine. There was no issue with connections between IBOutlet and label, .....

The correct code is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    HomeViewController *controller;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
         controller = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"iPadHomePage" bundle:  nil];
    }
    else {
         controller = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"HomePage" bundle: nil];
    }
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [controllers addObject:controller];
    navController.viewControllers = controllers;

    //this is the fix, by moving this 2 lines here
    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController]; 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That crash is unrelated to rotation. It seems in your nib, you have connected an element (likely a label) to an outlet in the code that no longer exists. You likely deleted a property or an instance variable named "labelName" but forgot to remove the connection in interface builder.

Comment: I remove all the connections, the error goes away, but when I add  connection again, again the error appears. I tried to add a new textField and use the assistant editor to create the connection, then again I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

this method should add to your tabbarController.m :

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:                                (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        return YES;
    }
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        return YES;
    }
    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
```

and this error"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key labelName" ,i guess is your tabbarController.view`s xib link a nonexist IBOutlet in the tabbarcontroller.

hope this can help you