# How to change One ViewController mode like Portrait to landscape in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, screen-rotation

I have Tabbar Controller and there I have 5 taps each having different-2 View Controller.
Now I want first ViewController (first tap) which rotate all modes like portrait, landscape left and landscape right etc. Then, I want remaining ViewControllers fixed in one mode like Portrait mode.
So how can do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610819/iphone-forcefully-change-orientation-from-portrait-to-landscape-on-navigation/11611306#11611306

Comment: And u really think since 29.6.2007 (first iOS) nobody asked that?!?! I'll help u: http://bit.ly/VDSrBi

Comment: Ya I know But my question is only one viewcontroller change and othes stay same in tab view controller ,

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
```

This method returns a specific orientation type you want. And this value can be set in each view controller.